# How integrate jSignature with php

Tags: php, jsignature

I need to put hand written signature to pdf.
This pdf is created by dompdf and it works fine.
Open pdf and put signature in pdf is to complicate for workers :)
This must be easy to use.
I find jSignature and I think its perfect for this project.
I didn't know jQuery.
My question is: How can I take signature (svg, png) to variable in php?